# Is there a standard library way to convert text to HTML entities in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, html-entities

I would like to take input with text that needs to be converted to HTML entities and output the HTML entities.

**Input:**

```
x < 7 && I like math && y > 7
```

**Output:**

```
x &lt; 7 &amp;&amp; I like math &amp;&amp; y &gt; 7
```

I could do this substitution manually using string manipulation, but I want to know if there is a standard library way to do this before rolling my own.

Comment: Take a look at `codepoint2name` in https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmllib.html?module-htmlentitydefs#module-htmlentitydefs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library [xml.sax.saxutils](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.utils.html) is standard and can escape and unescape xml in Python 2.7

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape, unescape

mystr = escape('x < 7 && I like math && y > 7')
print(mystr)
# x &lt; 7 &amp;&amp; I like math &amp;&amp; y &gt; 7
print(unescape(mystr))
# x < 7 && I like math && y > 7
```